# SSRS SharePoint Integration - Disaster recovery

Tags: reporting-services, disaster-recovery

I am adding a SQL Server Reporting Services in SharePoint integrated mode to an existing SharePoint 2007 farm (which has DR already).  The existing DR involves duplicate servers, and the content DBs would be restored from a backup.

If DR were executed without the Reporting Services server, will the farm still be able to run?

(Obviously functionality from the SSRS server would not be available, I am interested to find out if it will affect the rest of the farm if it were not available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it will run - just be careful with content (eg. pages) that may have had report viewer web parts added.

You can still deploy the report server add-in WSP files if you want to make the content display.